# want to view logged user company name, not id

Tags: php, laravel

I have two related Tables `$table->foreignId('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies');`

| users Table | companies Table |
| --- | --- |
| id | id |
| company_id | name |
| Second |  |

in view I want to show logged user company name

`{{Auth::user()->company_id->name}}`

pls help : (

Comment: You need to define this relation on your user model

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that many users can belong to a company, you'll want to define a [`One to Many` relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) between your `User` and `Company` models.

On your `User` model, add the following method.

```php
public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
}
```

Retrieving the name of the company for the currently logged-in user is done like so.

```
$name = Auth::user()->company->name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
{{Company::find(Auth::user()->company_id)->name}}
```

where `Company` is your company's model or you can define a [one-to-one relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) in your `User` model like so

```
/**
 * Get the company associated with the user.
 */
public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
}
```

And use it like this

```
{{Auth::user()->company->name}}
```